# how to apply class to all angular custom directives at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several custom directives in my application I'm building, and I want them to display well across all modern browsers.  I am wondering if there is a step somewhere in the angular lifecycle where I can check for custom elements and apply a class to them.  That way I can style them all at once and apply specific styles to the elements themselves as needed.

I know I could do this as part of the directive itself, but I'd like to do it globally without having to define that for each directive every time.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Unless you have really much directive declarations, you can simply add a class to the element in each directive declaration ?

Answer (score 0):

Use css attribute selectors in your stylesheet,  like [my-directive]{background:red;}
i do this often with [ng-click]{cursor:pointer;}